# Why is the size of SELECT smaller than INPUT in HTML

Tags: html, css

I was trying to create a form where I faced an issue: The size of SELECT and INPUT element are different.
In the following: why is the div with SELECT element smaller than the div with Input element (You can see a small gap with 'crimson' color).

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
  background-color: crimson;
}

.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

[class*="col-"] {
  float: left;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

.col-1 {
  width: 8.33%;
}

.col-2 {
  width: 16.66%;
}

.col-3 {
  width: 25%;
}

.col-4 {
  width: 33.33%;
}

.col-5 {
  width: 41.66%;
}

.col-6 {
  width: 50%;
}

.col-7 {
  width: 58.33%;
}

.col-8 {
  width: 66.66%;
}

.col-9 {
  width: 75%;
}

.col-10 {
  width: 83.33%;
}

.col-11 {
  width: 91.66%;
}

.col-12 {
  width: 100%;
}

div.addPost form {
  background-color: #F5F9FE;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1.2rem 1.5rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

div.addPost form select {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

div.addPost form [class*="col-"] {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="get">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <label for="">Post Title</label>
      <input type="text" maxsize="255">
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <label for="">Post Category</label>
      <select name="" id="">
        <option value="">First</option>
        <option value="">Second</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <label for="">Post Author</label>
      <input type="text" maxsize="255">
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <label for="">Post Category</label>
      <select name="" id="">
        <option value="">Draft</option>
        <option value="">Active</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I already tried assigning the same value to the font-size property for both the elements but that does not work. Please explain the reason for this. How do I remove this gap ?

Comment: because browsers render different fields with different styles. you have to adjust your styles to get the desired output (e.g. setting height or something for some elements)

Comment: The `input` has built in borders & padding which affect the size. Set those to 0 and the sizes match.

Comment: Try ```padding: 0.4%;``` to the select box, that should make your select box equal to input box.. But as like other comments the input has built in borders and padding and hence it looks bigger than select..

Comment: use a reset.css

Answer (score 8):

You need to use `box-sizing:border-box` in the INPUT and SELECT so that margin/padding is consider